# New Variable that counts based on row values in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create a new column that counts the number of rows that meet a value.

Creating replicable data:

```
data <- tibble(Category = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A"))
```

I **want** the data to eventually look like this code, but instead of just creating the variable manually like this, I create a new variable `CountA` using a conditional `mutate()` or something similar that counts the total number of rows where the value of `Category` is A only:

```
tibble(Category = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A"), CountA = c(4,4,4,4,4))
```

I know that I could filter out the non-A values and then generate the CountA variable, but I need to keep those rows still for a different purpose.

Comment: `data %>% mutate(CountA = sum(Category == "A"))`

Answer (score 1):

You can create a logical in `mutate`, then `sum` the number of `TRUE` observations.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(countA = sum(Category == "A", na.rm = TRUE))
```

Or in base R:

```
data$countA <- sum(data$Category == "A", na.rm = TRUE)
```

**Output**

```
  Category countA
  <chr>     <int>
1 A             4
2 B             4
3 A             4
4 A             4
5 A             4
```

If you are wanting to create a new column for every `Category`, then you could do something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  group_by(Category) %>%
  mutate(obs = n(),
         grp = Category,
         row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "grp", values_from = "obs", names_prefix = "Count") %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  select(-row) %>% 
  fill(-"Category", .direction = "updown")
```

*Output*

```
  Category CountA CountB
  <chr>     <int>  <int>
1 A             4      1
2 B             4      1
3 A             4      1
4 A             4      1
5 A             4      1
```